# Difference between depends and dependencies in gradle

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies

What's the difference between `depends` keyword and `dependencies` keywords in a gradle build file? I encountered these keywords in the following contexts:

depends:

```
project(':tools:bnd-module-plugin') {
  description = "bnd plugin to build moduleinfo with ${rootProject.description}"
  sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += project(':asm').sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  depends = ['biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd:3.4.0']
}
```

dependencies:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format'
  googleJavaFormat.toolVersion = '1.4'
  compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
  }
  dependencies {
    requires.each { projectName -> compile project(projectName) }
    depends.each { artifactName -> compile artifactName }
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0',
        'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.1.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
    testCompile project(':asm-test')
  }
}
```

Comment: @lu.koerfer post edited

Answer (score 1):

The `dependencies` keyword is provided by [a method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#dependencies-groovy.lang.Closure-) of the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance, which the `build.gradle` file is evaluated against. It allows the configuration of multiple types of dependencies via a [`DependencyHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html). You can add file dependencies, project dependencies and module dependencies, which can be resolved from Maven and Ivy repositories.

Since it is provided by the `Project` instance directly, it is available in **every** Gradle project.

The `depends` keyword does not exist in the Gradle API. However, Gradle provides a lot of possibilities to extend and program your build scripts. Via so-called *extra properties* it is possible to define additional properties in the scope of Gradle objects, like tasks and projects. Then these additional properties can be used like regular Gradle properties as in your example.

I found the [full build script](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/master/build.gradle) from your examples online. In the beginning of the script a `subprojects` closure is used to define *extra properties* for all subprojects:

```
subprojects {
    [...]
    ext.provides = []  // The provided java packages, e.g. ['org.objectweb.asm']
    ext.requires = []  // The required Gradle projects, e.g. [':asm-test']
    ext.depends = []   // The external dependencies, e.g. ['junit:junit:4.12']
    [...]
}
```

`provides`, `required` and `depends` are Groovy lists, which are then later used to store strings.

Your first code example sets a new list to the `depends` *extra property* of the `:tools:bnd-module-plugin` subproject.

Your second uses these lists to add module (`depends`) or project (`requires`) dependencies to all subprojects.

As you can see, `depends` is just part of a custom Gradle script and not part of the official Gradle API, unlike `dependencies`.